# How can I update model In Show component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

```
<Resource name="user-management" {...UserManagement} />


//UserManagement 
export default {
    show: MyShowComponent
    ...
}


const MyShowComponent = (props) => {
    const { record } = props;

return (
...
<span>
    <EmailField source="email" />
</span>

...

<ManageEmailComponent {...props} />
)
```

In `ManageEmailComponent` I have a modal with request to server to update email, how can I update  record from `MyShowComponent` without refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

You must provider an EditContext, and then inside you can put a SimpleForm as if you were in an Edit view.

So:

```
const MyShowComponent = (props) => {
    const {
        basePath,
        classes: classesOverride,
        ...rest
    } = props
    const { record } = useRecordContext(props); // Safer than const { record } = props; because sometimes react-admin passes the record by Context not props

    // Prepare react-admin controllers props for an Edit context
    const controllerProps = useEditController({
        ...rest,
        basePath,
        id: record.id, // The id is important !
        // onFailure, // If you want a callback
        // onSuccess, // If you want a callback
        undoable: false, // otherwise if child SimpleForm is not wrapped in ManyToManyReferenceContextProvider or something that overrides the "save" method, edit will never submit and dataProvider will be stuck forever. Don't know why, maybe a react-admin bug.
    })

    return (
    ...
    <span>
        <EmailField source="email" />
        <EditContextProvider value={controllerProps}
            {/* Here your are in a edit context, you can put your SimpleForm for example */}
        </EditContextProvider>
    </span>
```